# Duplication of CiviMail subject when delivered to an inbox

Tags: mosaico

Can anyone tell me why 'February 2021' is repeating and is there a way to stop it?  It only appears once in the Mosaico template I use as 'PreHeader Text' yet I can't seem to stop the duplication when I send a mail out.  image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gc3i.png

Comment: can you add screenshots to avoid any misinterpretation of the issue.

Comment: I've added a link as the image wasn't displaying.  Thank you @petednz-fuzion